# How are foreground services prevented from being shown on the Android screen saver?

Tags: android, maui

Currently, a text box is presented on the screen saver of the Android phone for my MAUI foreground service app. The text presented was provided as parameters for the `Notification.Builder` method. Is it possible to not have the text box presented when the screen saver is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official document said:

> Foreground services show a status bar notification, to make users aware that your app is performing a task in the foreground and is consuming system resources.

So you can hide the notification by [setting lock screen visibility](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification#lockscreenNotification).

I have tested it and it worked. Here is my code in the foreground service class:

```
var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
notification.SetVisibility(NotificationCompat.VisibilitySecret);
```

Comment: Actually, my testing revealed that the visibility attribute was effective only on the display of the actual notification, hiding it when triggered, and had no impact on the text box of the notification on the screen saver or the notification at startup of the app.

Comment: I tested it and the foreground service notification will not show on the lock screen. I can't make sure the text box of the notification on the screen saver you said is what. But if a notification has set the VisibilitySecret, it will not show on the lock screen. @MarcGeorge

Comment: Using


Notification notification = new 

    Notification.Builder(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, "98765")
        .SetContentTitle("Sentry")
        .SetContentText("Authorization Processing")
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.sentry)
        .SetContentIntent(BuildIntentToShowMainActivity())
        .SetOngoing(true)
        .SetAutoCancel(false)
        .Build();
    
    notification.Visibility = NotificationVisibility.Secret;
    
    MainActivity.notification = notification;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU0c1.png

Answer (score 0):

The suggested code addition (useful) is good for Xamarin based notifications, but for MAUI and the Android.App.Notification class, the following is
the necessary code:

`notification.Visibility = NotificationVisibility.Secret;`